# Check isPlaying() on another activity

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I've started a sound in activity A and want to stop it in Activity B. How can I do it?

Here's the code I'm using to start the sound:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(con, R.raw.siren1);
mp.start();
```

Thanks.

Edit:
Here's the solution:

Activity A

```
static MediaPlayer mp;
.........
mp = MediaPlayer.create(con, R.raw.siren1);
mp.start();
```

Activity B

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
        if (SmsReceiver.mp.isPlaying() == true) {
    SmsReceiver.mp.stop();
    }
finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare the MediaPlayer object as static and then refer to it from the other activity.

Comment: You mean like this:  private static MediaPlayer mp;  If so how can I refer it from the other activity? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably track your MediaPlayer object in a static class (Singleton design).  This way, you can access that object from anywhere.  Check this out: [Singleton Design](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)